# How to process AT&T token in solr index

Tags: solr, search-engine

I  have an index containing AT&T as a field , but when I search for this field we cannot put & sign in the query , so it is encoded to AT%26T. Searching for AT%26T returns nothing ,
Is there any way to use analyzer or filters to index this type of terms.

**NOTE :** I have used WordDelimiter analyzer with reserveOriginal=1 ...but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other reason than that shown by others is escaping special characters. You should escape all from the list:

`+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`

Just try use backslash before ampersand.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to search for `AT&amp;T`

Else you can find out in the admin/analysis what happens to the term AT&T in query and index stage. With verbose on, you can see excactly what analyzers do with your terms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tune WordDelemiter a bit further. See my adjustments I had made for jetwick to search for hashtags ala #java

https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick/blob/master/src/main/java/de/jetwick/es/JetwickFilterFactory.java#L49

The background: AT&T is normally tokenized as AT and T because '&' is removed as its no digit or character but with the class above you can make that the '&' sign is handled as digit and all stuff containing '&' signs will then be tokenized as 'AT&T' (and 'AT' and 'T' I think) but only if preserveOriginal=1 or you handle them as char, but then it won't split into 'AT' and 'T' I think as all positions of the string are detected as chars

BTW: you'll need to reindex and apply the same analyzer/tokenizer on the query string too!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use catenateWords="1". So that AT&T will me also indexed as ATT.
Also make sure your analyzer appears under both:

```
<analyzer type="query"> //this will define how the query is parsed and split into tokens before searching it
```

and

```
<analyzer type="index">// this will define how the field is indexed
```

If you only have this tag  <analyzer> than the analyzer will be used both on query and index time.